# request-promise error with response

Tags: javascript, request, promise

I am using the `request-promise` library to implement promises with my API calls. I had previously been using the standard `request` library, and by parsing the `json` I was able to get the result I desired. However, since changing to the `request-promise` library I am getting an error saying `[SyntaxError: Unexpected token u]`.

Can anyone spot something I am doing wrong?

see code below:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options = {
   uri: 'https://api.filtr.com/3.0/Spotify/5/gb/tracks?tag=happy'
}

rp(options).then(function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
  var body = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: `then()`’s function receives one argument, not three. Read the documentation for request-promise to find out what type of value `rp(options)` resolves to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options = {
   uri: 'https://api.filtr.com/3.0/Spotify/5/gb/tracks?tag=happy'
}

rp(options).then(function(body){
  console.log(body)
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: I tried to use your code and debug, but the debugger doesn't hit the "then" or "catch" block... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @WendyMunmunWang `Bluebird` has [longStackTraces](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.longstacktraces.html). In this case, you can simply use `require('request-promise').debug = true` to enable this feature.